# How to change style of a div more than once in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with the following content, for instance:

```
<div id="x">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

I want to be able to dynamically, through JavaScript, bold `ipsum` and then `amet`, for example, so the new text looks like this:

`Lorem **ipsum** dolor sit **amet**.`

The JavaScript code that I have can do this, but only once at a time. When I call `toBold("ipsum")` and then `toBold("amen")`, the function will only bold `met`. The function will only bold the argument in the last function call.

```
        var haystackText = document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;
        var replaced = "";

        function toBold (y) {
            var match = new RegExp(y, "ig");
            var boldText = "<div style=\"display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + y + "</div>";
            replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
            document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = replaced;
        }
```

How can I change this function so that both "ipsum" and "amet" are bolded?

Thank you for the help

Comment: What is passed to `toBold` as `y` ?

Comment: The word to bold in the div called "x"

Comment: Update `haystackText` with `replaced` on each call. Also what about just `<b></b>` or `<strong></strong>`

Comment: hopefully you do not match "div" or "font" after you get your issue fixed.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It works. I updated hayStack and used <b></b> instead of the div tags

Comment: How can I change the regex, so it only looks for the words to bold in the previous sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are problems with this method (*as @epascarello mentioned*), but the main problem here is that `haystackText` was never updated, and will always use the original value:

```
    function toBold (y) {
        var match = new RegExp(y, "ig");
        var boldText = "<div style=\"display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + y + "</div>";
        replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
        haystackText = replaced;
        document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = replaced;
    }
```

Also as I noted in a comment you can also use `<b>` or `<strong>` instead for bolding. [Here is a fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gx9h4p3c/).

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to pass an array to `toBold` , using `"(" + y.join(")|(") + ")"` as `RegExp` ; utilizing `replacement` function of `.replace()` to set each captured word

```js
var haystackText = document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;
var replaced = "";

function toBold(y) {
  var match = new RegExp("(" + y.join(")|(") + ")", "gi");
  replaced = haystackText.replace(match, function(match) {
    return "<div style=\"display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" 
           + match 
           + "</div>";
  });
  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = replaced;
}

toBold(["ipsum", "amet"])
```

```html
<div id="x">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w01tzoux/

**JavaScript**

```
function toBold(targetString) {

  var original = document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;

  var replaced = original.replace(targetString, "<b>" + targetString + "</b>");

  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = replaced;

}

toBold ("ipsum");
toBold ("amet");
```